# Какое событие постоянно мониторит input, независимо от фокуса в нем?

Tags: javascript, input, события

`сhange` только по смене фокуса. `keyup` только когда набираешь. А какое событие отслеживает любое изменение начение `value` даже если я к примеру при нажатии на любой селектор передал значение в инпут?

Приведу конкретный пример. При нажатии на `p` происходит изменение значения `value` у `input`, но при этом мой `div` не меняет bacground, как при событии `input`

```js
const $inp = document.querySelector('input');
const $p = document.querySelector('p');
const $div = document.querySelector('div');

$p.addEventListener('click', () => {
 $inp.value = $p.textContent;
});


$inp.addEventListener('input', () => {
 $div.style.background = "#fc0";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" >
<br />
<p>Text</p>
<br />
<div>Не меняется backgroud, когда меняется value input</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `p` происходило именно отслеживание input. Я понимаю, что могу просто написать функционал при нажатии на `p`, но такое не подходит. Потому что `input` может менять значение при куче событий в моей задаче.

Comment: Вы наверно о addEventListener ?

Comment: нет, я уже про  input.addEventListener('`событие изменения`, () => {})

Answer (score 2):

данный пример показывает работу

- oninput - сразу
- onchange - при потере фокуса

а ещё, как вызвать эти два события с помощью JS

```js
var myInput, demo;
myInput = myInput || document.getElementById("myInput");
demo = demo || document.getElementById("demo")

function doOnInput() {
  demo.innerHTML = "on Input: " + myInput.value;
}

function doOnChange() {
  demo.innerHTML = "on Change: " + myInput.value;
}
setTimeout(() => {
  myInput.value = 'Напиши change'
  let e = new Event('change')
  myInput.dispatchEvent(e)
}, 3e3);
setTimeout(() => {
  myInput.value = 'Напиши input'
  let e = new Event('input')
  myInput.dispatchEvent(e)
}, 5e3);
```

```html
<p>Напиши, вставь или удали какой-нибудь текст в поле ниже:</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="doOnInput()" onchange="doOnChange()" value="здесь" />
<p id="demo"></p>
```

как подписаться на эти события с помощью JS:

```
myInput.addEventListener('input' , (_e) => {} )
myInput.addEventListener('change', (_e) => {} )
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я все понимаю это. Просто у меня задача, в которой есть функционал, который меняет значение `input` при нажатии на совершенно другой элемент, берет `textContent` с `p` и кладет в `value`. По сути в этот момент около инпута должен появляться крестик, но этого не происходит. Потому что не `input`, ни `change` на это не работают. Только из ES7 `observe`, которым можно весь дом отслеживать постоянно.

Comment: dispatchEvent вам в помощь

Comment: или какой-нибудь фреймворк, например viperHTML

Comment: не, можно конечно с прокси поизвращаться, но я всё же рекомендую `dispatchEvent`

Comment: спасибо. Я думал, что смогу найти решение на чистом JS, я даже обновил вопрос для ясности. Видимо не смогу)

Comment: я с вас очень сильно удивляюсь, я говорю про  Ч И С Т Ы Й  js `dispatchEvent` я даже привёл пример его использования а так же `Proxy` https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy

Answer (score 1):

Событие input

Событие input срабатывает тут же при изменении значения текстового элемента и поддерживается всеми браузерами, кроме IE8-.

вот тут читайте подробнее https://learn.javascript.ru/events-change

Comment: Ниже в комментарии написал почему мне это не подходит